# WebCodec: how to flush without restarting from key frame

Tags: webcodecs

In WebCodec, if I do a `decoder.flush()` to ensure that all frames are decoded, I need to restart after with a key frame (i.e. not a delta frame). But this is really annoying as my goal is to decode a video in real time to play it at x1 speed, therefore since I decode frame by frame I do not always restart on a key frame:

```
decoder.configure(…);
decoder.decode(frame[0]); // this is a key frame: ok
decoder.flush(); // to obtain the decoded frame
decoder.decode(frame[1]); // this is NOT a key frame ==> ERROR!
```

I also tried not to use `flush` at all, but then it seems like it waits to see multiple frames before starting the decoding… which I don't want of course.

Another possibility I can imagine is to decode in advance the 250 next frames in one go (until finding a new key frame), but then it seems like quite dirty… Is there a better option I am missing?

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/webcodecs/issues/220

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks! So what is the best workaround? Do you know why decoder have this constraint?

Comment: @tobiasBora What codec are you using? That will help others to answer you better (_eg:_ If your codec was H264, for example, and you could also put that data into MP4, then frame-by-frame would be possible in a video tag without even needing WebCodecs. Also such an issue (of needs multiple frames) would happen in H264 because of B-Frames and a difference in their Decoding order vs Presentation order. They would not be sequential).

Comment: Thanks, It was h264, but I got the answer to my question (cf my answer here). But what do you have in mind when saying that frame-by-frame is possible without using WebCodecs? I tried to simply change the time but it was way too imprecise to be reliable.

Comment: @tobiasBora the formula is: Get an offset as 1 second divided by FPS _eg:_ where input video rate is 30 FPS it is... `offset = ( 1 / 30.000 );`, then step frame-by-frame using `video.currentTime += offset;`.

Comment: @VC.One : the problem of this is that `currentTime` is not frame-precise. I found no reliable way to get precisely the n-th frame, sometimes the above formula fetches the frame before or after, even if I add a small constant to it to avoid rounding errors. This is discussed here https://github.com/w3c/media-and-entertainment/issues/4

Comment: @tobiasBora Thanks for the info. That Github discussion was an interesting read. So onto your problem... I test mostly in Chrome using MP4. What I found out back in the day was that there is a difference between **frame-step-plus_1** versus **seek-to-frame_N**. The Seek-Frame-N method does need a constant as you correctly noticed.  You must multiply the above `offset`  with `(frameNum - 1)` then set time as `video.currentTime = (offset + 0.005);`. I will just make a code Gist and a live demo on Github when I get a chance. Seems like a problem where many people need a possible solution.

Comment: @tobiasBora PS: the above assumes you're using a zero-based index. For example: Testing an SMPTE timecoded frames, where second **0** is made from frames 0 up to 29, followed by second **1** which is from frames 30 up to 59 and so on etc...

Comment: I was definitely considering a zero-based index and I tested various constants, it was working fine with the first few frames, but started to randomly diverge at some points, e.g. at frame 1949 in my test. Similarly, stopping was sometimes stopping a few frames to late. WebCodecs are more complicated, but at least more reliable as I always know which frame is printed on screen…

Answer (score 0):

So with the great advices of sanderstan [here](https://github.com/w3c/webcodecs/issues/753), I realized that all codecs might differ, and that the driver used to decode might also differ, even on the same browser (e.g. for license issues, I think that firefox uses the decoder provided by the system to decode multiple codecs). For instance, some codecs might need 10 frames to output a first frame; this can notably be explained because some frames need to know the n-1-th and the n+1-th frame to be decoded, and sometimes the order of the frame in the video does not match the order of the final frames (order of presentation)

Moreover, `flush` should only be used when reading the last frame of a video. So the trick instead is to send many decode, until:

- either we have enough outputted frames
- or the queue of unprocessed messages is too large (say `decodeQueueSize` is bigger than 3), meaning that the decoder struggles to process the frames. In that case, we can wait for this queue to be smaller (cf for instance the `dequeue` event) before adding new elements.

The best example I could find is https://webcodecs-samples.netlify.app/audio-video-player/audio_video_player whose code is here https://github.com/w3c/webcodecs/tree/main/samples/audio-video-player